# How to structure a database for daily user data?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, eve, database

I have this simple user database in my mongoDB that I access using python eve :

```
'user': {
    'schema': {
        'firstname': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'lastname': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'username': {
            'type': 'string',
             'unique': True
        },
        'password': {
            'type': 'string'
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to store for each user daily data.

Should I create a single database called data and store all the users and the daily action like this :

```
'data': {
    'username' : {
         'type': 'string'
     },
    'day': {
         'type' : 'string'
     },
    'action': {
         'type' : 'string'
     }
}
```

Let us say I have 1000 users and I keep track of the data for 100 days. There will be 100000 entries in the database. If I want to retrieve all the data for one user, will it possible to do so reasonably fast ?

Is there a more efficient manner ?

Comment: I know virtually nothing about MongoDB I have no idea how efficient it will be but perhaps you can have an array in the user table where each element is what they did on the nth day as well as store the day they signed up. Also, how are you storing all of their activity for the day in a string?

Comment: Just a reminder, if you are not doing yet. Be careful when storing passwords, you will be safer storing the salted hash instead. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943258/save-password-as-salted-hash-in-mongodb-in-users-collection-using-python-bcryp#27943613) to do it with `flask` and `mongodb` using bcrypt

Comment: I would say calling your database/collection `data` would be a bad idea as it could literally refer to anything. I would suggest using a more descriptive name. e.g. `dailyUsers`